# Going to math grad school with low GPA

Tags: soft-question, education

I am a pure mathematics major and I want to do Ph.D in math, however I want to change to Applied math. I have a low  3.2 < GPA < 3.3 though.

I have taken most of Pure math requirements, and sadly got C in Algebra (group theory), and C+ the 2nd course Analysis and both of them were honors courses. I messed up my Analysis grade mainly because the 1st course I took in Analysis was not the honors version of the class, and in the 2nd course a lot is assumed that I didn't cover in my regular Analysis course, and messed up my Algebra grade because I was having some family issues which affected my performance in school. And basically these two grades brought my GPA down.

So next year I am planning to take some grad courses in Analysis and Algebra and maybe some Applied math course.

I am planning to take the subject GRE exam in September and the general GRE in June, and also want to take the Basic and most possibly qualifying Algebra exams in my school (to at least show in my application that my grade doesn't represent what I know in the subjects), and let's assume I get really good scores (I hope :)).

I have done research in Jet Propulsion Laboratory, NASA one semester, but it was a lot of programming and astronomy, nothing related to math. I also did comet observation with one pretty famous astronomer in a national observatory. I have also been working for almost a year in a research group that does work related to physics, and I do data analysis there and work with their web.
I don't have any publications.
This summer I am going to do research in applied math in my school.

And maybe this will help-I am a female and was a transfer student.

Basically, my plan is to apply to as many schools as possible. Do I have a chance to get into a Phd program in applied math?

Thanks

Comment: This question is probably better suited for Academia:SE.  I'm interested in what people have to say though.  I am also dead-set on graduate school, but my overall GPA is a $3.3$.  Math GPA is around there too.  Fortunately for me, I have two years of undergrad left.  It's scary though because you hear of people with GPA $> 3.7$ and struggling to get into many places.  At any rate, best of luck!

Comment: You still have a chance to bring it up! Good luck! And yes, I see people with high GPA's and some research experience and they don't get anywhere and I am really scarred. And I didn't know about Academia:SE, thanks for the info! :)

Comment: I agree with Kaj. It's much better suited for Academia.SE (not only for the reasons Kaj listed but also because these kinds of questions are met with some hostility here). For what it's worth, I think your application is okay but definitely not as strong as many applicants. The way to overcome that will be research experience IN APPLIED MATH. I highly recommend that you change gears and work with someone in applied math (be it fluids, mathematical physics or what have you). Strong research in applied math will help to offset any weak points in your application for graduate studies.

Comment: Also, applied mathematicians use math a lot, so don't neglect your pure math studies ;). A lot of applied mathematicians definitely are not very good mathematicians but the strongest applied mathematicians are those that have a good foundation in pure mathematics.

Comment: Thanks @CameronWilliams! Should I delete the question from here?

Comment: No definitely don't since others may have some good input, but definitely crosspost it over at Academia.SE.

Comment: Thanks! I actually want to have really strong background in Pure math, that's another reason why I want to take the grad courses in Analysis and Algebra. Thanks for the input! :)

Comment: I think you have a shot, there are many many good schools and a lot of resources in applied math. The research experience and good letters to demonstrate you're a serious participant will do much to circumvent the trouble you may have had in courses. Course work and research are quite removed in some regard so the metric of excellent course work is not optimal, more interestingly, do you present creative potential, are you persistent in long projects etc... these are measured hardly at all in standard course work.

Comment: It sounds like you're currently at a big school - if, as an undergrad, you do well in graduate courses similar to what you would take as a first-year grad student, that will help your application a lot.

Another thought: don't feel like you have to get into the perfect Ph.D. program right away. It might be easier to get into a Masters program at a "lesser" school, where you will still be able to prove yourself to the Ph.D. Institution that you really want to get in to. Absolutely aim for your favorite school, but don't feel like that door is closed if you don't get in right away.

Comment: This question should be migrated to Academia.SE.

Comment: I posted it in Academia.SE, is there a way to show it over here? Btw I got way more responses over here than in Academia.SE, so thanks a lot everyone :)

Answer (score 3):

What you should do is to look for prospective advisors doing research that interests you, contact them and try to get some experience in that subjects. Academics are always looking for <strike>cheap labor</strike> interested graduate students for their projects.